# Why won't this short bit of code work?

Tags: text, applescript

Just a quick question:  What's wrong with the following AppleScript code?  What it's supposed to do is get the position of a text item (separated by a user-provided delimiter) within a string.  But thus far, it doesn't work.  Script Debugger simply says, "Can't continue return_string_position" without any specific errors.  Any ideas as to what's wrong?

```
tell application "System Events"
    set the_text to "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    set word_index to return_string_position("jumps", the_text, " ")
end tell

on return_string_position(this_item, this_str, delims)
    set old_delims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delim
    set this_list to this_str as list
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of this_list
         if item i of this_list is equal to this_item then return i
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to old_delims
end return_string_position
```

Answer (score 0):

The tell system events command is incorrect and should be excluded. Also, you don't need to use text item delimiters of " " to make a list of words, simply use "every word of". Lastly, your code will only return the last match of the passed parameter, this will return EACH match.

```
on return_string_position(this_item, this_str)
    set theWords to every word of this_str
    set matchedWords to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theWords
        set aWord to item i of theWords
        if item i of theWords = this_item then set end of matchedWords to i
    end repeat
    return matchedWords
end return_string_position

return_string_position("very", "The coffee was very very very very very ... very hot.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that System Events thinks the function `return_string_position` is one of its own (if you'll look at the dictionary, you'll find that it isn't). This is very easily resolved; just add `my` before the call to `return_string_position`.

Your new code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set the_text to "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    set word_index to my return_string_position("jumps", the_text, " ")
end tell
...
```

Or you can use adayzdone's solution. In this case, his/her solution is perfect for the job because there really isn't any need to target system events when working with simple textual things.